# What value is selected into parameter in SQL query without where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlparameter

For example, I have this query

```
SELECT @param = column from table
```

What value is pulled into @param?

I tried this and can't figure out the value that is being pulled. It is not the old record or newer one.

Comment: use `SELECT @param` to see the value

Comment: It's unlikely to be any value that makes sense, because SQL data is stored as unordered sets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql) states:

> the variable is assigned the last value that is returned

But without a `WHERE` clause that uniquely identifies a row nor an `ORDER BY` clause that specifies a unique value for ordering, the row chosen for the variable assignment is undefined and not deterministic when the table has more than one row.

You could add `ORDER BY` to the query to return the last ordered row. A more efficient method to do that would to be use `SELECT TOP(1)...ORDER BY...DESC`. Conversely, `SELECT TOP(1)...ORDER BY...ASC` will return the first ordered row. Again, the order by column(s) need to be unique for a deterministic value.

Comment: Even with `WHEN` it could be more than 1 row.  With `ORDER BY` it will be predictable.

Comment: @PM77-1 Why would it be predictable with an `ORDER BY`?

Comment: @MattGibson - It *could* be predictable as long as the order used uniquely identifies the last row.

Comment: @PM77-1, consider `SELECT @param = column from table ORDER BY SomeOtherColumn`, Multiple rows with the same `SomeOtherColumn' value but with a different `column` value would be unpredictable.

Comment: @PM77-1 I understand that that's almost certainly what SQL Server will do, but I'm not entirely convinced that it *has* to do that, i.e. that the behaviour is guaranteed.

Comment: Please see my clarification.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the specifics in the documentation. While I'm generally very happy with MS's documentation, I always seem to find this particular kind of detail hard to track down myself...

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I know that we have to use Where, order by to get the desired result. Just curious to know what is the result without any filter conditions.

Comment: @Anurag, the result with is undefined in that case. You may get a different results depending on the indexes defined on the table, the session isolation level, or whether SQL Server chooses to use a parallel plan.

Answer (score 0):

This is the value in the column referenced. It seems like it should have a TOP 1 in it, with a WHERE Clause designed to fetch 1 row only.